# Add to home Screen propmpt not showing using manifest json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I need to add prompt for ADD TO HOME SCREEN using manifest.json but it is not showing while my pwa score in audit is 100%

I have dist folder like below:-

[image]

My Manifest json consisting below:-

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "short_name": "xyz",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/xyz/static/img/icons/xy-icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/xyz/static/img/icons/xy-icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "xyz/index.html",
  "scope": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#0628b9",
  "theme_color": "#000000"
}
```

and i am using workbox plugin for service worker and i tried with normal service worker too like below :-

sw.js

```
var VERSION = '20';

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(caches.open(VERSION).then(cache => {
    return cache.addAll([
      'https://cfjedimaster.github.io/nomanssky/client/index.html'
    ]);
}))
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
  var tryInCachesFirst = caches.open(VERSION).then(cache => {
    return cache.match(e.request).then(response => {
      if (!response) {
    return handleNoCacheMatch(e);
  }
  // Update cache record in the background
  fetchFromNetworkAndCache(e);
  // Reply with stale data
  return response
});
});
  e.respondWith(tryInCachesFirst);
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(caches.keys().then(keys => {
    return Promise.all(keys.map(key => {
      if (key !== VERSION)
    return caches.delete(key);
}));
}));
});

function fetchFromNetworkAndCache(e) {
  // DevTools opening will trigger these o-i-c requests, which this SW can't handle.
  // There's probaly more going on here, but I'd rather just ignore this problem. :)
  // https://github.com/paulirish/caltrainschedule.io/issues/49
  if (e.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && e.request.mode !== 'same-origin') return;

  return fetch(e.request).then(res => {
    // foreign requests may be res.type === 'opaque' and missing a url
    if (!res.url) return res;
  // regardless, we don't want to cache other origin's assets
  if (new URL(res.url).origin !== location.origin) return res;

  return caches.open(VERSION).then(cache => {
    // TODO: figure out if the content is new and therefore the page needs a reload.
    cache.put(e.request, res.clone());
  return res;
});
}).catch(err => console.error(e.request.url, err));
}

function handleNoCacheMatch(e) {
  return fetchFromNetworkAndCache(e);
}
```

and my pwa score in lighthouse is 100%.
[image]

but i am not able to see the prompt add to home screen.

Comment: Have you totally cleared out your browser and uninstalled any previous installs? It remembers if you answered no to a previous prompt and does not prompt if you have already installed.

Comment: Have someone else try on their device

Comment: Which device and which browser are you testing with? The automatic prompt only works with Android Chrome & Edge. Other browsers are manual A2HS.

Comment: Thanks Mathias for prompt response! I am tesing it on chrome browser. Sometime it shows but thereafter it doesn't show after deleting the icon too. It prompted once but not now.

Comment: Chrome desktop or android?

Comment: Chrome Desktop and i am using Vue JS so i am pointing to index.html

Comment: Should prompt again after you delete icon from chrome://apps/  and clear everything in the browser. Also perhaps try clearing and shutting down chrome. Most likely you will see it work on another machine or if you try in Android Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. It is woking now but the background color and theme color not showing as defined. suggestion appreciated!

Comment: It's probably working, but Chrome desktop is most confusing. When you click on the link here chrome://apps/  it opens the standalone app, but may leave you in the browser view. On my mac, I see the icon in my dock toolbar and have to click that to see the standalone version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177256/discussion-between-ritwik-kumar-and-mathias).

Comment: How can i prompt for add to home screen without application > add to home screen. I am using below but no luck and getting below error:- 

Banner not shown: beforeinstallpromptevent.preventDefault() called. The page must call beforeinstallpromptevent.prompt() to show the banner.

Comment: Are you not seeing the A2HS prompt again?

Comment: It is not coming automatically, I need to go in application > add to home screen. so i am trying it with beforeinstallpromptevent.

Comment: Still in Chrome desktop?

Comment: You cannot generate the A2HS dialogue yourself. So yes use beforeinstallpromptevent. My tester is here if you want to see an example. https://a2hs.Glitch.me  - Instead of the pop-up it will show the button. ONLY in Chrome (Desktop & Android) and (Android & Edge bowser)

Comment: how can i test it on Edge browser on desktop? doesn't it support iOS 11.4.1?

Comment: Android & edge not desktop

Comment: Ok, Thanks!  doesn't it support iOS 11.4.1?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I don't have a device to test that on.

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I just tested not working. I will update here if it works

Comment: Perhaps try asking @edgeDev on Twitter. They seem fairly responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing/debugging A2HS, most of the work is clearing out previous tests and installs.
Over and over again.
Browsers intentionally remember what was done last time so the user is not pestered with install prompts.
Totally clearing out the cache may be necessary if you want to see the prompt again.

If you said no to a previous prompt, it will not ask again for XX months.
If you already installed, it should not ask again.

A few things to look for
-- in Desktop Chrome
-- Remove icon from chrome://apps/
-- If that does not work, you may need to clear the cache